# Sitecore commerce SXA Asset Optimizer not working

Tags: sxa, sitecore-commerce, sxa-storefront

I am working on Sitecore commerce project where I am customizing the cart and product listing pages.I am trying to debug Sitecore commerce knockout JavaScript and modify the JavaScript necessary in Sitecore commerce.When i try to view SXA storefront pages and inspect the sources loaded on the page, the pages are optimized and bundled so i can not debug it. 
To disable asset optimizer,, I have tried steps from https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/enable-and-configure-the-asset-optimizer.html and https://www.bugdebugzone.com/2018/07/sitecore-sxa-disable-asset-optimizer.html 
but none of them are working and I am always seeing the bundled version of JavaScript loaded on to SXA pages.

Can anyone let me know what should i do to disable optimization and see all the sources java scripts loaded from Sitecore themes folder

Here is the screenshot of SXA storefront JS panel

[image]

Comment: did you try adding a query string of `?aodisabled=1`

Comment: What is the version of Sitecore commerce you are using?

Comment: It is sitecore 9 update 3.I tried adding ?aodisabled=1 and it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have tried all the options, the only way to disable optimization of styles and css is to navigate to `\App_Config\Modules\SXA\Foundation\Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Theming.config` and modify the following value to `true` and that will let you enable and disable asset optimization switch

```
<setting name="XA.Foundation.Theming.AssetsOptimizationSwitch.Enabled" Value="true" />
```

Note, that this switch is only available in SXA version used in Sitecore Commerce 9 Update-3. It is not available in previous versions of Sitecore Commerce.

Comment: This solution worked finally.Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, try to globally disable asset optimization:

[image]

You can also disable it per site:

[image]

If you still want to use `?aodisabled=1` ensure that this "switch" is enabled. Take a look at `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Theming.config` configuration file and find `XA.Foundation.Theming.AssetsOptimizationSwitch.Enabled` setting:

[image]

Comment: This post helped me as well.

I noticed there is a typo in the official documentation of Sitecore SXA. It suggests to use "?aodisable=1" instead of "?aodisabled=1".

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/the-asset-optimizer.html